# During enabling Xcode Server fails with "Could not export API server SSL..."

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, xcode-server, xcode-bots

After updating Xcode to latest version Xcode Server can not be turned on. It fails with error:

```
Could not export API server SSL certificate: Error Domain=XCSSecurity Code=-1 "OpenSSL: Error decrypting key
4304406060:error:06FFF089:digital envelope routines:CRYPTO_internal:bad key length:/System/Volumes/Data/SWE/macOS/BuildRoots/5b2e67f8af/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-75.60.3/libressl-2.8/crypto/apple/hmac/hmac.c:188:
4304406060:error:06FFF078:digital envelope routines:CRYPTO_internal:keygen failure:/System/Volumes/Data/SWE/macOS/BuildRoots/5b2e67f8af/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-75.60.3/libressl-2.8/crypto/evp/evp_pbe.c:166:
4304406060:error:23FFF073:PKCS12 routines:func(4095):pkcs12 algor cipherinit error:/System/Volumes/Data/SWE/macOS/BuildRoots/5b2e67f8af/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-75.60.3/libressl-2.8/crypto/pkcs12/p12_decr.c:83:
4304406060:error:23FFF075:PKCS12 routines:func(4095):pkcs12 pbe crypt error:/System/Volumes/Data/SWE/macOS/BuildRoots/5b2e67f8af/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-75.60.3/libressl-2.8/crypto/pkcs12/p12_decr.c:133:
" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=OpenSSL: Error decrypting key
4304406060:error:06FFF089:digital envelope routines:CRYPTO_internal:bad key length:/System/Volumes/Data/SWE/macOS/BuildRoots/5b2e67f8af/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-75.60.3/libressl-2.8/crypto/apple/hmac/hmac.c:188:
4304406060:error:06FFF078:digital envelope routines:CRYPTO_internal:keygen failure:/System/Volumes/Data/SWE/macOS/BuildRoots/5b2e67f8af/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-75.60.3/libressl-2.8/crypto/evp/evp_pbe.c:166:
4304406060:error:23FFF073:PKCS12 routines:func(4095):pkcs12 algor cipherinit error:/System/Volumes/Data/SWE/macOS/BuildRoots/5b2e67f8af/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-75.60.3/libressl-2.8/crypto/pkcs12/p12_decr.c:83:
4304406060:error:23FFF075:PKCS12 routines:func(4095):pkcs12 pbe crypt error:/System/Volumes/Data/SWE/macOS/BuildRoots/5b2e67f8af/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-75.60.3/libressl-2.8/crypto/pkcs12/p12_decr.c:133:
}
```

Development and Xcode Server runs on the same Mac machine.
I have tried to restart xcscontrol, but it did not help.

```
sudo xcscontrol --reset
```

In my case here is no **SWE** folder at this location:

```
/System/Volumes/Data
```

**How I could fix "Could not export API server SSL..." error?**

[image: Error when trying to enable presented when enabling Server & Bots (Xcode Server)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that needs to install macOS 12.3 beta and use Xcode 13.3 beta or 13.2.1.

If here is another way on fixing this problem I would like to know.

More discussion can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/693646?page=3).